# Web API Request is null in ExecuteAsync method of ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to access the `Request` property in my `ApiController`-derived class.

For some reason, `Request` is null in `ExecuteAsync` method. I've seen the other questions, so before you ask:

- I am **not** initializing the controller by calling the constructor, it's a regular HTTP POST API call from an external device.
- I've tried the same request locally with Fiddler, the behavior is identical.
- I am not unit testing.
- Before hitting the `ExecuteAsync` method, my request passes through a delegating handler, and in the delegating handler, my request object exists (I even add some properties without any problem).
- At the last line of delegating handler, I call `return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);` without a problem and `request` **exists**.
- Right after than in API controller, `HttpContext.Current.Request` is not null and accessible without problem.
- In API controller, `RequestContext` is not null and accessible without problem.
- In that same line, `Request` is null.

Why would this occur? I'm on Web API 2.2 (and MVC 5, if relevant).

Comment: If possible, can you show your POST API call? It might be that the external device is not forming the request properly. Did you try testing the API with a Postman or any REST client?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I've just tried with Fiddler upon your comment. Unfortunately, it's still the same.

Comment: The RequestContext is a part by the Request (can also be obtained by Request.GetRequestContext()). Can you check how the request is created at the client side? Also, you may check HttpContext which can also give you information about individual requests.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh what do you mean by the client side? I've already tried with two different clients, they are regular HTTP requests with nothing special. I'm pretty much sure it's not the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that you're trying to access HttpContext while working with async/await.

So, you have two options:

1. Access the request via the ExecuteAsync method 'HttpControllerContext' parameter - controllerContext.Request.
2. Make sure your web.config is targeting .NET 4.5 and update appSettings with   aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext set to true.

You can read more here - [Using HttpContext Safely After Async in ASP.NET MVC Applications](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Using-HttpContext-Safely-After-Async-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications).

To better understand what's going on under the hood, I'd recommend:

1. Understand what is SynchronizationContext - [ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/)
2. Understand how it is related to ASP.NET - [Understanding the SynchronizationContext in ASP.NET](http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html).

In a very very high level: in a synchronous server implementations, where the entire request is processed by the same thread, the execution context is stored using TLS (thread local storage), means HttpContext is available anywhere in your code.

In an asynchronous server implementation (async/await), the request **may** be processed by several threads, and there's a need to pass the execution context between those threads.

Comment: <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" /> in the web.config

Comment: Option 2 seemed easier but it didn't work for some reason (it was still null). Option 1 worked. I'd be happy to learn about the reason though.